# How to check for big files?

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I tried to do like this but not works, any ideas?

```
if(Test-Path ~\desktop){

    $bigfiles = Get-ChildItem ~\desktop -force -Include *.* | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt 10GB}

    if{$bigfiles -gt 10GB){

        echo "You have big files"
    }
}
```

this is the error:

```
Cannot compare "C:\Users\mario\Desktop\AngelinaJolie_photo_in_4k.jpg" because it is not IComparable.
At line:7 char:8
+     if($bigfiles -gt 10GB){
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotIcomparable
```

Comment: Anyway, you cannot compare Angelina to anyone :-)

Comment: If there are no files above 10GB, the $bigfiles will be empty ($bigfiles.Length -eq 0 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$bigfiles is $null if there are no results, a `FileInfo` if there is one result, otherwise it is an array of `FileInfo`s. You can check for results using

```
if($bigfiles) { ... }
```